# Attempting to write Raspberry Pi 3/4 OS, Stuck on testing serial connections to hardware

Tags: c, operating-system, raspberry-pi3, uart

I am a learning software engineer attempting to create my own Raspberry Pi operating system for the Raspberry Pi 3 and 4. I started by following this guide here: https://jsandler18.github.io/tutorial/wrangling-mem.html which got me through memory management for a Pi 2. And then decided I would start working on things on my own! Following this guide we have been using qemu to emulate the pi 2! Which I ported into a 64bit version that can be emulated with qemu for the pi 3. I use this qemu command `qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3 -serial stdio -kernel kernel8.elf` to emulate the small little shell I have built.

I am not super advanced in actual computer engineering and have little experience with hardware. So I got somewhat overwhelmed when the guide started getting into hdmi drivers and graphics. So I decided I would attempt to get the OS working with just a serial connection first. When using qemu that seems to work fine, but then I attempted to load my kernel onto actual hardware. I formatted the partitions of my sd card for FAT32 (one boot another with data) and put these files onto it:

```
 - bootcode.bin
 - fixup.dat
 - kernel8.img
 - start.elf
```

Now one thing to note is that I am writing to my SD card using one of those usb stick sd card reader/writers, and everytime I plug it in I get a Windows error asking me to repair it, I am unsure why it seems to think this. Should I try scanning and fixing it? I normally don't do any development in Windows, but I noticed this when I decided to copy the file over in my Windows Host environment.

Using this USB to GPIO converter [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07554Z4LX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07554Z4LX) with the default driver Windows installed. I plugged in the GND, TX, and RX headers into the proper pins (6, 8, and 10) and used the power cable that I purchased with this pi. I then used putty to open up a serial connection over the port with a Baud rate of 115200. Looking around online it looks like most the other settings I could keep the same. Then I plugged it in. The raspberry pi 3 blinked a green light twice. But the putty serial terminal just remains blank. I am not super familiar with UART (I know what it is but this is the first time I have actively used it). So I think it might be an issue with that. I checked and fixed a bunch of castings to wrong sizes(issues from the switch to a 64bit OS from a 32 bit) and then did some research. I am not sure if I am attempting to use a serial connection wrong or if the guide I followed was not actually going to work on real hardware in that way. If you have any questions or ideas please let me know! I kinda have a feeling it could also be that I never flush data, (which I have in the past with serial stuff) but I didn't think that would matter over direct GPIO pins. I also saw online that in the Pi 3s and 4s the GPIO pins are not the actual UART points of a sorts, that they are like a sub UART element. The UART part I pretty much copied from his guide and since it worked in the emulator I was satisfied for a while. But my lack of knowledge of actual Hardware has started showing!

A guide I used to attempt to connect serially:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uart+on+pi&t=ffab&ia=web

Here is my github repo if you are interested. The master branch is my 32 bit attempt I plan on adding more platform layering to actually incorporate the 64 bit version once that works. I know this is a mess, but I was hoping to get a solid working 64bit and 32bit version and then clean it up! I also know I have two list implementations! Another thing on the bucket list!
https://github.com/icampbell-rit/ianos/tree/64bit

Comment: @Fredrik well I was attempting to write my own OS/kernel onto the bare hardware but it would be primarily software like a normal OS. Another guide this one: https://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones suggested I just really need to put my kernel and those 3 other files onto the sd card...

Comment: @Fredrik according to my research the graphics card on the Pi has a boot loader that executes the files I put onto the partition on the SD card! But that means they have to be named properly, which is why I have to name my kernel kernel8.img

Comment: It's a bootable USB @Fredrik.  You're only adding to the confusion.

Comment: @Kcvin yeah it appears that is how the PI treats any SD card in it's slot!

Comment: kernel8 implies you're using AArch64 mode (ARMv8) which is 64-bit.  You mention your image is currently 32-bit.  Have you tried renaming to kernel7.img?

Comment: @Kcvin well I have a working emulated 32-bit (Pi2) and a working emulated 64-bit branch for the Pi3. My kernel8.img was cross compiled with AArch64 mode. Is that not do able on a Pi3? Either way I guess I can create another branch for the Pi3 in 32-bit mode!

Comment: Also does Uart0 vs. UART1 matter?

Comment: Just curious, do you have any experience with other programming languages?

Comment: If you configure UART0 you should have usb adapter connected to UART0 pins, yes.  Also make sure you're TX and RX pins aren't reversed.  Adapter TX should go to Pi RX, Pi TX should go to adapter RX.

Comment: Using `puts` before the hardware is initialized (`uart_init()`) is generally a no-no.

Comment: @Kcvin so then which pins goto which? Like is the green goto the pis tx or rx then? And ahh you think that might mess up the hardware? It doesn't mess up the emulation though? And yeah I have experience in C, python, MIPs, ARM, Bash, C++ and Java. I just have never done anything this low level before. As in I have never done C without the Windows/Linux libraries. C is my probably most fluent language as well as favorite.

Comment: @Kcvin So I updated the puts that I called before uart_init and fixed that. Working on finding UART0 pinout as well. Hopefully it might work? Damn...still no dice, trying to figure out UART0 vs. 1 on the pi

Comment: I would guess that there isn't a UART1 based on the looks of this pinout: https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/73950-102-12-339300/pi3_gpio.png .  Green wire should go to GPIO15 (RXD0).

Comment: @Kcvin Okay I tried that and it still gave me two green blinks and nothing on the terminal. I am wondering If I should try something other than Putty? Idk, at this point I am unsure what else might be wrong. What else would cause no output? I mean if the UART worked I would get something right?

Comment: the best advice I can give right now is to continue to look up resources online, especially be on the lookout for tutorials that match the current hardware setup you have.  If the tutorial still doesn't work, try reaching out to the authors.  You might also be able to find help on RPi community forums.

Comment: Thanks @Kcvin! I appreciate all the effort you have put in!